# reactjs update array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to update an item in an array of objects.

**DATA**

```
const branches = [
   { id: 1, avail: true, name: "branch1" },
   { id: 2, avail: false, name: "branch2" } // update the name to branch 2 and avail to true
]
```

**action.payload data**

```
{ id: 2, avail: true, name: "branch 2" }
```

**branchReducer**

This is working just fine but I wanna ask if its the correct way to update an object inside an array ?

```
 case 'UPDATE_BRANCH': {
        const payload = action.payload
        return {
            ...state,
            branches: state.branches.map(item => item.id === payload.id ? { ...item, ...payload } : item) 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I mean.. I wouldn't jam it all into 1 line, but yes that looks like the correct way to modify an item while maintaining state immutability.

Comment: How you measure if something is correct? Its readable, immutable and working so whats bad?

Comment: @DennisVash Im new to react so I'm not sure thats the right way to update the branch state. That's why im asking

Comment: Maybe will help https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data